# Jquery - Selecting circular area of an image

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to select both rectangular and circular areas within an image, not to crop them, but to create dynamic mapped areas inside an image. So far, I know how to enable the selection of rectangular areas but haven't found a way to do circular selections and be able to save geometry values of the created circle within an image. Any library or plugin I could use?

Comment: are you looking for area tag of image map have a look at this link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp  hope this helps

Comment: That's the approach I was thinking to display the mapped areas but I need to have a page where user defines these areas. A similar approach of an image cropping but with circular areas.